# basic authentication did not accepted in fireFox

Tags: javascript, ajax

My main problem is when I send this wrong username and password other navigators (Chrome , IE and Edge they encode them and replace the xxx with encode 64) but in firefox, it stays xxx and then the server doesn't accept it and keep the first value that he logged in within the first place.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "url",
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic xxx"
  }
})
  .done(function() {
  // If we don't get an error, we actually got an error as we expect an 401!
  alert('fail');
})
  .fail(
  function() {
    // We expect to get an 401 Unauthorized error! In this case we are successfully 
    // logged out and we redirect the user.
    window.location
      .replace(url);

  });
```

Comment: Could you precise a bit more? Where your `xxx` comes from? Could you share more code?

Comment: jQuery.ajax({type : "POST", url : "inicio.do",
      async : false,
      dataType : 'json',
      username : 'logmeout',
      password : '123456',
      headers : {
       "Authorization" : "Basic xxx"
      }
     })
     .done(function() {
      // If we don't get an error, we actually got an error as we expect an 401!
      alert('fail');
     })
     .fail(function() {
// We expect to get an 401 Unauthorized error! In this case we are successfully 
// logged out and we redirect the user.
        window.location
          .replace(url);
        
       });

Comment: this is all my code

Comment: Which version of jQuery did you use?

Comment: i used jquery 3.4.1